# Row-wise sum of values grouped by columns with same name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame where several columns may have the same name. In this small example, both column "A" and "G" occur twice:

```
    A  C  G  A  G  T
1   1 NA NA NA  1 NA
2   1 NA  5  3  1 NA
3  NA  1 NA NA NA  1
4  NA NA  1  2 NA NA
5  NA NA  1  1 NA NA
6  NA  1 NA NA NA  1
7  NA  1 NA NA NA  1
```

I wish to create a data set with *one* column per column name. For each row, the individual column values should be replaced with the sum (`sum(..., na.rm = TRUE)`) of the values within each column name. For example, in row two, the two individual "A" values (`1` and `3`) should be replaced with `4`. I don't know in advance which column names that occur several times.

The expected output would then be:

```
#     A  C  G  T
# 1   1  0  1  0
# 2   4  0  6  0
# 3   0  1  0  1
# 4   2  0  1  0
# 5   1  0  1  0
# 6   0  1  0  1
# 7   0  1  0  1
```

So I guess I could do something like:

```
noms = colnames(dat)
for(x in noms[duplicated(noms)]) {
  dat[ , x] = rowSums(dat[ , x == noms], na.rm = TRUE)
}
dat = dat[,!duplicated(noms)]
```

But this is a bit clunky and for loops are meant to be evil. Is there any way to do this more simply?

Comment: You want to sum by row columns with the same names?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can transpose `dat` , calculate `rowsum` per group (`colnames` of the original `dat`), then transpose the result back to original structure.

```
t(rowsum(t(dat), group = colnames(dat), na.rm = T))
#  A C G T
#1 1 0 1 0
#2 4 0 6 0
#3 0 1 0 1
#4 2 0 1 0
#5 1 0 1 0
#6 0 1 0 1
#7 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 3):

We could split the dataframe by name using `split.default` and take the row-wise sum using `rowSums` to create one column for each unique name.

```
sapply(split.default(df, names(df)), rowSums, na.rm = TRUE)

#  A C G T
#1 1 0 1 0
#2 4 0 6 0
#3 0 1 0 1
#4 2 0 1 0
#5 1 0 1 0
#6 0 1 0 1
#7 0 1 0 1
```